# Finding whether a list is in descending order or not

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion

I am currently learning recursive functions and i have solved this question partially.

For example,if the input is [4,4,3],the output should be true.The successive element has to be at least as big as the previous one.

Here's my code:

```
def descending(l):
    x=0
    if len(l)==0 or len(l)==1:
        return True
    for value in range(0,len(l)):
         if l[value]>=l[value]+1:
             x=l[value]+1
             descending(l[x:len(l)])
             return True
         else:
             return False
```

Do let me know why my logic fails for certain cases.

Comment: Why are you setting `x` to `l[value] + 1` (one of the values in the list) and then trying to use it as an index (`x:len(l)`) in the very next line?

Comment: That is my only question regarding recursion. My other questions are as follows: why are you using recursion for this problem? It isn't very well suited for it. Why are you using an awkward `for value in range(0, len(l))` instead of iterating over the values in the list directly? (It's also confusing that you're calling it `value` when clearly it's an index...) What is the purpose of `x`?

Comment: Totally off topic, but please don't use `l` as a variable name - it looks too much like `1`.

Comment: I thought that after comparing the first 2 elements,i would have to pass the list from that element onward.That's why i was assigning x the next value and starting my list from that point onward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this function to be recursive, it should look like this :)

```
def descending(l):
    if len(l) <= 1 or (len(l) == 2 and l[0] >= l[1]):
        return True
    else:
        if l[0] >= l[1]:
            return descending(l[1::])
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Yup, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Okay, now consider an empty list...  How about just checking `len(l) < 2`?  Checking inequalities is generally safer than checking for equalities when dealing with ranges.

Answer (score 2):

If u want to use recursion, you can do it like this:

```
def foo(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return True
    f, *l = l
    return False if f < l[0] else foo(l)
```

But I strongly not recommend you use recursion for this kind of problems.

Little remark for syntax: `f, *l = l` will set `f` to first element of `l` and set `l` to rest part of l, it same to: `f, l = l[0], l[1:]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the key failure of your code is that `descending()` returns a value but when you call it recursively, you ignore its return value!

I'm not sure which of the previous answers is more *Pythonic* than the other but I don't like their style.  I'd first clearly lay out your base cases and then end with the recursion:

```
def descending(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return True

    if array[0] < array[1]:
        return False

    return descending(array[1:])
```

I also have a personal hangup against *return-else-return* logic:

```
if x:
     return a
else:
     return b
```

vs. simply:

```
if x:
    return a
return b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def decreasing(l):
    if l==[] or len(l) == 1:
        return(True)
    else:
        return( decreasing(l[1:]) if l[0] > l[1] else False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works, but it could easily be more pythonic.

```
def descending(l):
    if not l or len(l) == 1:
        return True
    elif l[0]>=l[1]:
         return descending(l[1:])
    else:
         return False
```

Comment: Just remove the parenthesis after "value in l" and it should be working !

Comment: @Sygmei Why would that work? If `l` is a simple, 1D list this will blow up with a `ValueError: Too many values to unpack`

Comment: I just noticed that by removing the parenthesis and trying :P

Comment: Sorry, I think it is fixed now. I missed the enumerate function :)

Comment: I made it better now, with some inspiration from @Sygmei but I think mine's a bit clearer :)